# How can I vertically align in an anchor element of variable length?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS that generates from a database options for answering questions. I would like to keep the clickable area of the options at a maximum so that whenever the user clicks on anywhere on the green the link is actually clicked.

My difficulty is that I can't align vertically the text within the link e.g. for Option 1 and 3 and 4 the text is centered at the top.  I can't use a fixed line-height since some of the options can be a longer text like it is the Option 2, and then that would look strange with a lot of space between the lines.

Could you please help me find a solution to vertically align the text of the links in the middle.

There is some javascript as well associated with the class "sm2_link" and the code is generated by a Drupal 7, however these are irelevant details that do not play a role in the solution of this difficulty. I'm mentioning it just for completion.

Many thanks

```css
.exercises {
  display: inline-grid;
  row-gap: 2vw;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto;
  column-gap: 10vh;
}

.exercises label.option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exercises label.option a {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  min-width: 15vw;
  max-width: 70vw;
  min-height: 15vh;
  text-align: center;
  /*    line-height: 3; */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.exercises input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.exercises .form-type-radio {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit-question-0" class="form-radios exercises">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-7" name="question_0" value="7"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-7"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option1.mp3">Option 1</a> </label>

  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-3" name="question_0" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-3"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option2.mp3"> Option 2 that has a very long text that should be broken down on several lines if it becomes too long for the display, I still need to type something more, like Lorem ipsum to make this text longer and display it on several lines</a> </label>

  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-2" name="question_0" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-2"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option3.mp3">Option 3</a> </label>

  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-4" name="question_0" value="4"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-4"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option4.mp3">Option 4</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tags can't be aligned. They're just text in a file. _Elements_ can be aligned and manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
}

strong {
  display: contents;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
.exercises {
  display: inline-grid;
  row-gap: 2vw;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto;
  column-gap: 10vh;
}

.exercises label.option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exercises label.option a {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  min-width: 15vw;
  max-width: 70vw;
  min-height: 15vh;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.exercises input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.exercises .form-type-radio {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

strong {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit-question-0" class="form-radios exercises">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-7" name="question_0" value="7"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-7"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option1.mp3">Option 1</a> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-3" name="question_0" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-3"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option2.mp3"> Option 2 that has a very long text that should be broken down on several lines if it becomes too long for the display, I still need to type something more, like Lorem ipsum to make this text longer and display it on several lines</a> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-2" name="question_0" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-2"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option3.mp3">Option 3</a> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-0">
    <input class="exercises form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-question-0-4" name="question_0" value="4"> <label class="option" for="edit-question-0-4"><a class="sm2_link no_dl" href="option4.mp3">Option 4</a></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my issue but in certain labels I have <strong> tagse.g. "Option 2 that has a <strong>very long text that should be broken down on several lines if it becomes <strong>too</strong> long for the display, I still need to type something <strong>more</strong>, like Lorem ipsum to make this text longer and display it on several lines". When I apply your solution this label goes haywire, with some text on the upper line while others lower line. It's available in the codepen the I posted initially. I would award you the answer though as you have fixe the original question

Comment: @MMT I don't understand. What's the problem? What's your goal?

Comment: In the real example the text "Option 1" is actually "Opti<strong>on</strong> 1". When the  <strong>tag is added in the label text then the label is mis-aligned. You can check this out at the same code-pen: https://codepen.io/marceltudor/pen/jOeBYwa   It is visible especially on the Option 2, on the long text. If you could provide a solution that would keep the same alignment even when the label has <strong> in it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @MMT I get it. Add the following CSS: `strong { display: contents; }`. See my edited answer.